# OEM license activation for Windows 10 Home VirtualBox guest, on Ubuntu host

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, virtualbox, windows-activation, oem

## Context

Three years ago my company got me a Lenovo T550 with Windows 10 Home installed on it (my understanding is that this is called "OEM"). I immediately erased everything to install Ubuntu on it.

Unfortunately from now on I will need to use Windows 10 a few times a week for legacy reasons, but my main work is still on Ubuntu, so I am thinking of **running Windows 10 within VirtualBox within Ubuntu**.

## Lenovo recommendation

Lenovo told me that my Windows Home license is somehow linked to my hardware (firmware?) and that Windows will automatically find this out. They pointed me to [this page](https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/solutions/ht000616):

> The installation of Microsoft Windows Server 2008,2008 R2 SP1, 2012, and 2012 R2 from Lenovo OEM media to such a virtual machine will fail until the virtual BIOS has been updated to include this information. setVMBIOS.exe performs this function for servers using Microsoft Hyper-V technology.
>
> Consult your hypervisor vendor for information on how to perform this function on other hypervisors. [...] The fix resolves this issue by **adding Lenovo information to the virtual BIOS**.

*Note: That page does not mention Windows 10 Home, but I guess the same applies?*

## VirtualBox

How to apply Lenovo's recommendation to VirtualBox? (5.2.18)

Right now I have out-of-the-box VirtualBox and the VM I created yesterday with standard settings does not activate:

[image: Windows sucks]

> Windows is not activated. Windows reported that no product key was found on your device. Error code: 0xC004F213

Answer (score 25, accepted):

On the Ubuntu host, type this command:

```
sudo strings /sys/firmware/acpi/tables/MSDM
```

This will print out a few lines, the last line being the activation key contained in the laptop's firmware:

```
MSDMU
LENOVOTP-N11  
PTEC
#####-#####-#####-#####-#####
```

Within the Windows guest:

1. Click the search loop.
2. Type `activation`.
3. Click the `Activation settings` item that appears.
4. Click the `Change product key` button.
5. Enter the activation key obtained from Ubuntu command above.
6. Click `Activate`.
7. The following should appear:

[image]

[image]

At least that worked for me :-)

Comment: This sounded like the answer I needed - but unfortunately I do not have the file /sys/firmware/acpi/tables/MSDM - my laptop is a lenovo P1 and I run ubuntu 20.04.1